# How to play somersault animation during jumping at top point like in Contra games in 2D game (godot, gdscript)?

Tags: 2d, animation, godot, jumping, gdscript

Here is my jumping code:

```
if is_on_floor():
    if Input.is_action_just_pressed("ui_up"):
        motion.y = JUMP_HEIGHT
    if friction == true:
        motion.x = lerp(motion.x, 0, 0.2)
else:
    if motion.y < 0:
        $Sprite.play("Jump")
    else:
        $Sprite.play("Fall")
    if friction == true:
        motion.x = lerp(motion.x, 0, 0.05)
```

But I want also add the somersault animation at top point like in Contra games from NES. How can I detect moment where I should play and stop this animation. Should it be related to animation frames count and play speed?

Comment: Just playing animation once at appropriate velocity doesn't do the trick?

Comment: @Ocelot in that case that speed will depends on animation speed